# Align Navbar Fully Left and Split into 12 Sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like my `navbar` to be divided into 12 sections with each element taking up 1 section, i.e have 12 elements in the `navbar`. I would also like them to start from the very left of the screen, instead of what I currently have in the image below;

[image]

I thought `container-fluid` and `navbar-left` would align the elements fully to the left of the `navbar` but I am really struggling in trying to move them over.

**What I Have Tried (my code so far)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contracts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Processes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Filing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Am I able to A) Align all the elements in the `navbar` fully to the left and B) Divide the `navbar` into 12 "sections" that each element shall take one of?

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7.

Comment: there is a class `.nav-justified` but it not supported because of a bug in safari check this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/justified-nav/#)

Comment: try this `<ul class="nav nav-justified">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `row` class to the `container`:

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contracts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Processes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Filing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7u01ju1/)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Any advice on how to divide the bar into 12 elements?

Comment: @CBreeze You can either add 12 items with `class="col"` and it will use flexbox to make them equal width or you can use the suffix `-1`, e.g. `col-md-1` because the Bootstrap [grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options) uses a 12 column grid.

Answer (score 0):

A) 
I think you have to take away the `container` class in the first line, like that:

`<div class="container-fluid">`

B)
You can add the `col-md-1` Bootstrap class to the `li` elements, like that:

`<li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Directories</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the navbar you created you will find some padding/margin left generated by bootstrap, just add your own class to that element and set margin or padding you want. You can create as many li elements as you want.